# Bug with expanded namecard

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, user-card

So users with more that 1000 reputation have [expanded namecard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user). Normally, when browsing questions, users below that will not have it. However, when reviewing questions and answers, it still appears for users below 1000 rep. Image: [image: This!].
 Is this a bug or is it supposed to be like this?

Answer (score 5):

It's supposed to be like that. The usercard on /review is not the same as the expanded usercard for which you need 1000 rep. The /review usercard shows the amount of reviews you have done, and the expanded usercard shows a part of your "about me".

Comment: Then could it just be a tooltip?

Comment: @UniKitty In a tooltip, you cannot simply wrap an image and such like in the /review usercard.

Comment: I mean it should say "This user has X today, Y this week and Z total" not put an image

Comment: Why? A usercard like this looks better, doesn't it?

Comment: True, that's not really a user card, just some useful stats packaged together in a neat design.